# Is [limits] useful as tag?

Tags: discussion, meta, burninate-request

Here on Meta we have a tag [limits](/questions/tagged/limits). It doesn't come with a wiki. There are no watchers for that tag.

Looking at the 52 questions in that tag you'll find ones about question bans, input limits, voting limits, technical limits.  I wouldn't say that tag will ever describe the question, except that the word by itself is part of the content of the  question. That doesn't add anything you can't search for.

Asking about limits is on topic on MSE but the types of limits are broad and without context, a question tagged with only [limits](/questions/tagged/limits) is missing obvious context.

I propose those 52 questions are re-tagged with their correct context tag:

- [character-limit](/questions/tagged/character-limit)
- [voting-limits](/questions/tagged/voting-limits)
- [daily-reputation-limit](/questions/tagged/daily-reputation-limit)
- [answer-limit](/questions/tagged/answer-limit)
- [rate-limiting](/questions/tagged/rate-limiting)

For the remainder of the questions the tag should be removed.

Those actions should lead to a burnination of the tag [limits](/questions/tagged/limits).

Comment: *cue 2 Unlimited song* — the [rate-limiting] is another possible correct tag for some of the questions.

Comment: When you say limits, with no other qualifiers, my brain immediately jumps to calculus. Excepting questions about lim(x→∞) or lim(x→0), "limits" by itself is too vague.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling my brain has limits, it doesn't jump ...

Comment: @rene See, never would have imagined that :)

Answer (score 4):

The [limits](/questions/tagged/limits) tag isn't useful, as already addressed in another answer.  As for what to do about it, I suggest a refinement to your plan: retag with the listed tags **where that adds value**, in batches no larger than ten total retaggings per day, and then burninate [limits](/questions/tagged/limits).  In some cases, like old closed questions that have other relevant tags already, we can just let the burnination nuke it without replacement.  For example, I saw a closed question already tagged [reputation](/questions/tagged/reputation); adding [reputation-limits](/questions/tagged/reputation-limits) there won't help anybody, so just skip it.  It's ok to not tag every nuance of a question if the tags that are already there are sufficient.  If somebody comes across the question later and organically adds tags, that's fine but not required.

Comment: When should we start? I could do five today...without disrupting the homepage too much.